# Putting a rectangle around matrix nodes?

Tags: tikz-pgf, matrices

I built up a simple UML diagram, where one of the class boxes has an union containing a number of elements. I want to show that those elements are part of an union.

But how can I do so with tikz? I tried to use a matrix, but it complains that I cannot nest matrices.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,positioning,calc,arrows,shapes}

\tikzstyle{class}=[matrix of nodes, draw=black, font=\ttfamily\small]

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm]
    \matrix (value) [class] {
        \textbf{Value} \\
        \hline
        TypeA m\_type \\
        \textit{Union:} \\ % TODO: want to have a rectangle around the next 6 entries!
        TypeB int64Val\\
        TypeC float64Val\\
        TypeD stringVal\\
        TypeE *funcVal\\
        TypeF varsVal\\
    };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please always provide an example that can be copy&pasted to compile (so it should in particular include all `\tikzlibrary` statements and not reference any nodes or styles not defined in the example).

Comment: @Caramdir done :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

[...]

\draw (value.north west) rectangle (value.south east);
\draw ($(value.north west)!(value-3-1.north west)!(value.south west) + (4pt,0)$) rectangle ($(value.south east) + (-4pt,4pt)$);
```

The first coordinate in the draw statement is the projection of `(value-3-1.north west)` (top left anchor the the first node in the third row) to the line between `(value.north west)` and `(value.south west)` and then shifting 4pt to the right.

[image: result]

Comment: Ohh great! I'm sorry for not mentioning that I have a frame around the "class" box too. I would like to have both the class frame and the union frame have some little space. Can I do that easily?

Comment: Hmm, maybe there is some "scale" utility or something, that scales the rectangle around its center? Ideally I would like to tell the "draw" command: "Draw the rectangle X pt smaller than the coordinates given".

Comment: @Johannes: See the updated answer

Comment: @Johannes: Try to set the `inner sep=<value>` option on the outer box.

Comment: @Martin: That wouldn't just have pushed the inner box outward too in my original solution.

Comment: „would”, not “wouldn't”.

Comment: @Caramdir: I see. The box margins and paddings (seps) still confuse me. In TikZ as well as in CSS.

Comment: @Martin: I TikZ padding (=inner sep) is part of the width, in CSS I think it isn't (except in old IE versions).